# Can a deterministic finite automaton ever go into an infinite loop?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, theory

As the title suggests, is this possible? Or does it halt execution when it hits the trap state? Thanks to anyone who can clear this up.

Answer (score 28):

A deterministic finite automaton can only go to infinite loop if the input string is infinite. For finite inputs, the automaton stops when the input string ends. For infinite inputs, for example the automaton for regex `0*1` will loop infinitely if the input string is an infinite sequence of `0`.

Comment: To add to this, a [Two-Way DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_finite_automaton#Two-way_deterministic_finite_automaton) *can* go into an infinite loop on finite input, but every two-way DFA is equivalent to a loop-free one-way DFA.

Comment: Is language membership defined for infinite strings, and regular languages?

Comment: @kutschkem Wasn't given the definitions we used during the uni formal languages course. For that matter for us strings were defined as finite sequences to begin with. But under definitions that permit infinite strings it may be possible to also amend the definitions for the various models to make it work.

Comment: @kutschkem Lookup Buchi automata. Typically when dealing with infinite strings the acceptance condition changes. Instead of "when you read the string you end up in an acceptance state" you say (for example) "when reading this infinite string you pass through an acceptance state an infinite number of times". There are a few alternatives that give rise to different automata which may or may not have different levels of power in recognizing languages of infinite strings. For example: typically non deterministic automata are not equivalent to deterministic ones.

Comment: The definition of a regular language is precisely those strings accepted by a DFA. An infinite string cannot be accepted by a DFA, so therefore it cannot be a member of a regular language.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta "typically non deterministic automata are not equivalent to deterministic ones." What's your definition of "equivalent"? You can always take an NFA and produce a (possibly exponentially larger) DFA that accepts the same language.

Comment: @jmite I don't see how a two-way DFA can go into an infinite loop. It still consumes one character at each transition, and exits once the input is empty.

Comment: @chepner A two-way automaton is defined specifically to not (necessarily) do that: instead of consuming the input one character at a time, the transition function dictates which way the read head moves on the input tape. So there's nothing stopping it from moving left->right->left->right... But these loops are detectable, so we can always make an equivalent one-way DFA.

Comment: @chepner For finite words, not so for $\omega$-words. [Deterministic Buchi automata are strictly less expressive than non deterministic Buchi automata.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton#Recognizable_languages)

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Yes, but that seems to beg the question of whether a DFA and a Büchi automata are the same thing, just with different rules about how they recognize languages. (Functionally, is there an difference between a DFA and a BA given a finite input?)

Comment: @chepner My comment spawned from the OP asking about whether you could define membership & regular languages for infinite strings. I answered yes and the automata that do so are Buchi/Mueller/Rabin ecc automata. Obviously you have to extend the notion and this brings us to the fact that in the infinite string case many automata's power depends on whether they are deterministic or not, which for the finite case does not happen. Anyway "structurally" a Buchi automata is the same as a DFA, it has states, transitions and acceptance states. The difference is the acceptance condition.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks. My comments stemmed from ignoring that kutschkem's question could include things like -languages.

Answer (score 13):

The DFA performs a single state transition on each read input symbol, reads each symbol of the input exactly once, and halts when the input string is exhausted. In order for an infinite loop of state transitions to happen, the input string has to be infinite. DFAs are usually defined for finite inputs only, as the automaton's output is defined by what state the automaton is in after the input string has been exhausted (something that will never happen for infinite strings).

However, the concept of the DFA has been generalized in a way it can be applied to infinite input strings as well: the omega automata (often written as ω-automata) will accept a string if the entire execution fulfills some acceptance condition. A typical example is the Büchi automaton, which functions otherwise as a normal DFA or NFA, but only accepts input strings that cause the automaton to be in an accepting state infinitely often.